# Unable to share a folder between Windows 7 and Ubuntu (running in VMWare)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, file-sharing

I have installed vmware toolbox in ubuntu (guest OS). I tried to share a location from the settings of the virtual machine. But when I click Ok, the following error in thrown in the host (Win 7) OS.

**"Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: Unknown error."**

The location is not showing up in /mnt/
What could be the reason?

P.S I have vmhgfs process running in my Ubuntu VM.

I was following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/) method.

Comment: I also have this problem with CentOS, but only certain VMs.

Answer (score 1):

From [VMware Fusion 3.1 Release Notes](http://www.vmware.com/support/fusion3/doc/releasenotes_fusion_31.html) (for openSUSE, but may apply to your case) :

> **Install GCC in order to install VMware Tools and to share folders in
>   openSUSE 11.3.**
>
> VMware Fusion 3.1 does not include
>   prebuilt kernel modules for openSUSE
>   11.3. If you want to use openSUSE 11.3, you must install the gcc compiler prior to installation of
>   VMware Tools, so that the kernel
>   modules can be compiled during Tools
>   installation. Without the compiler
>   installed, trying to enable shared
>   folders produces the alert, "Unable to
>   update run-time folder sharing status:
>   Unknown error".

So, did you install VMware Tools and gcc?

Comment: gcc came with Ubuntu. I installed VMWare tools later.

Answer (score -1):

Go to ‘Shared Folders’ option under virtual machine’s settings. Browse the Windows 7 folder or partition you want to share with Ubuntu.

Note: Any network between both Operating Systems not required.

1. VirtualBox Shared Folders in Ubuntu GuestNote down the Share Name. ‘Make Permanent’ option if you want all the time.
2. Guest OS will detect this share if guest additions installed and started properly. We have to mount this share inside Ubuntu guest. To do it, create a folder on any location.

   Let's say create a folder inside media folder called ‘ windows7share’

   ```
   sudo mkdir windows7share
   ```

   VirtualBox Shared Folders in Ubuntu Guest
3. Now we have to mount the VirtualBox shared folder to above folder with following command.

   ```
   sudo mount -t vboxsf H_DRIVE /media/windows7share
   ```

   VirtualBox Shared Folders in Ubuntu Guest
4. That’s it. It should work without any issues. You could see the all folders and files from particular Windows 7 partition. Creating files and folders from Ubuntu guest worked well and You can see them from Windows 7 too, because ‘Read Only’ option was not selected.

   Virtualization software
5. Once you restart this virtual machine, the above mount will disappear. To make this mount and virtualbox shared folder access permanent,

   Make sure to select *Make Permanent* option in step 1.

   Add the command used in Step 3 to  `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file, to run the command every time when system starts up.

   Hope this will help you.

Comment: Um, he asked about vmware, you answered about virtualbox